# Java regex, delete content to the left of comma

Tags: java, regex

I got a string with a bunch of numbers separated by "," in the following form :

```
1.2223232323232323,74.00
```

I want them into a String [], but I only need the number to the right of the comma. (74.00). **The list have abouth 10,000 different lines like the one above.** Right now I'm using String.split(",") which gives me :

```
System.out.println(String[1]) =
1.2223232323232323 
74.00
```

Why does it not split into two diefferent indexds? I thought it should be like this on split :

```
 System.out.println(String[1]) = 1.2223232323232323
 System.out.println(String[2]) = 74.00
```

But, on String[] array  = string.split (",") produces one index with both values separated by newline.

And I only need 74.00 I assume I need to use a REGEX, which is kind of greek to me. Could someone help me out :)?

Comment: If you're using String.split(","), why not just keep one of the indexes in the array?

Comment: `String.split(",")[1]` would be what you are looking for

Comment: Or wait a minute... I see the problem. The key line is: **"The list have abouth 10,000 different lines like the one above."** That's why you want a regex... because apparently you don't want to loop through them all (or you have not thought about that possibility)

Comment: Avoid using `String` as a variable name, since it is the name of a class. Variable names in java should start with a lowercase letter. Also, the indexes in the result should be 0 and 1, not 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If it's in a file:**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("..."));
sc.useDelimiter("(\r?\n)?.*?,");
while (sc.hasNext())
  System.out.println(sc.next());
```

**If it's all one giant string, separated by new-lines:**

```
String oneGiantString = "1.22,74.00\n1.22,74.00\n1.22,74.00";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(oneGiantString);
sc.useDelimiter("(\r?\n)?.*?,");
while (sc.hasNext())
  System.out.println(sc.next());
```

**If it's just a single string for each:**

```
String line = "1.2223232323232323,74.00";
System.out.println(line.replaceFirst(".*?,", ""));
```

**Regex explanation:**

`(\r?\n)?` means an optional new-line character.
`.` means a wildcard.
`.*?` means 0 or more wildcards (`*?` as opposed to just `*` means non-greedy matching, but this probably doesn't mean much to you).
`,` means, well, ..., a comma.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**`split` for file or single string:**

```
String line = "1.2223232323232323,74.00";
String value = line.split(",")[1];
```

**`split` for one giant string (also needs regex) (but I'd prefer `Scanner`, it doesn't need all that memory):**

```
String line = "1.22,74.00\n1.22,74.00\n1.22,74.00";
String[] array = line.split("(\r?\n)?.*?,");
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) // the first element is empty
   System.out.println(array[i]);
```

Comment: Your split line work fine when I use your String line. But If I use the string with the 10 000 data lines it gives med an output of : 
74.00
1.2131414114

And I dont understand why.. each line in the document is in a newline.

Comment: @iNzzane Edited. Try the second option.

Comment: Your regex did work, the split did not. I suppose it's because its a newline. And the next line first number will be combined with the line before. Anyhow thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
String[] parts = "1.2223232323232323,74.00".split(",");
String value   = parts[1]; // your 74.00
```

Comment: The problem is if I write : 
String[] parts = "1.2223232323232323,74.00".split(",");
And do syso(parts[1]) the output is :
"1.2223232323232323" (newline) "74.00" I assumed it should be parts[1] = 1.22323etc.. and parts[2] = 74.00 but its not..

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strings = "1.2223232323232323,74.00".split(",");
```